# Logstash count output

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to do a simple task with logstash : I need to count the loglevel on a log file. I tried to use the metrics filter.

For doing my test I use a simple file like this:

```
INFO
WARN
INFO
WARN
INFO
WARN
INFO
```

And I use this conf file :

```
input {
    stdin { type => "api" }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}" ]
    }

    if [loglevel] == "WARN" {
        metrics {
            meter => "warn"
            add_tag => "metric"
        }
    }
}

output {    
    if "metric" in [tags] {
        stdout {
            codec => line {
                format => "warn count: %{[warn][count]}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The warn count is exact, I get this output:

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Logstash startup completed
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
warn count: 3
Logstash shutdown completed
```

Can anyone explain me why I always have 9 lines in output ? How can I do to get only one line ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html):

> Metrics are flushed every 5 seconds by default or according to flush_interval.

and

> clear interval ... if set to -1, the default value, the metrics will never be cleared

Try setting those to values you would prefer.